# PSConfig fails at task 5 of 6

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, psconfig

When I run PSConfig after install CU, I get this error.

> *"Performing configuration task 5 of 6 Upgrading SharePoint Products... Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products. An exception of
>   type System.InvalidOperationException was thrown.  Additional
>   exception information: Cannot open log for source 'SharePoint 2010
>   Products Configuration Wizard'. You may not have write access." When I
>   access to PCDiagnostics logs, it says  "An exception of type
>   System.InvalidOperationException was thrown.  Additional exception
>   information: Cannot open log for source 'SharePoint 2010 Products
>   Configuration Wizard'. You may not have write access.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open log for source
>   'SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard'. You may not have
>   write access. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The RPC
>   server is unavailable    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
>   at System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.OpenForWrite(String
>   currentMachineName)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.InternalWriteEvent(UInt32 eventID,
>   UInt16 category, EventLogEntryType type, String[] strings, Byte[]
>   rawData, String currentMachineName)    at
>   System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal.WriteEntry(String message,
>   EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID, Int16 category, Byte[] rawData)
>   at System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry(String message,
>   EventLogEntryType type, Int32 eventID)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.Tracer.WriteEventLog(String
>   trace, EventLogEntryType eventType, Int32 eventid)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.Tracer.TraceException(Exception
>   e, String error, Int32 eventid)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskDriver.Run()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PsconfigCommandLineMain.Main(String[]
>   args)"*

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: `Additional exception information: Cannot open log for source 'SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard'. You may not have write access.` The user you are using, is this user the farm admin and has all access to the server itself?

Comment: Yes, it's the farm admin and has full permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this behavior every single time we applied a CU to our SharePoint farms (2007 and 2010). **When running the wizard a second time it ran through all steps in 99.99% of all cases.** Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried to run the wizard but it also fails at step 9. Same error with PSConfig.
My Sharepoint is version 2013 but I don't understand why it gives a error for Sharepoint 2010.

Comment: Up until now I never experienced this with our 2013 farm. For that we also now started using this script which significantly reduces the time to patch the farm. maybe it can be of help here? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/russmax/2013/04/01/why-sharepoint-2013-cumulative-update-takes-5-hours-to-install/